# How to handle Android Push Message from the system tray?

Tags: android, push, handle

In my app I get push message from Azure Notification Hub. When my app in the background the push message goes to the system tray.

When the user clicks the push message it brings the app to the foreground. I want to redirect the user to a specific Activity of my app. I don't know how it can be done. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the app is in the background the data will be sent as an extra bundle. You can handle it like this in your launching activity or splash screen.

```
  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
          Check the data and redirect to the required activity from here.
    }
```